# Angular 4 - Add Days to a Date in HTML template

Tags: html, angular, date

I have taken a public variable which is used to save date of first day of the week, or say it indicates a weekend. It is fetched from database. 
I want to take Date (Numbers only) of the next week.

[image]

I have tried following code, but is not working.

```
public selectedWeekend: Date;

<table>
    <tr>            
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            Mon
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            Tue
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            Wed
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            Thu
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            Fri
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            Sat
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            Sun
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            {{ selectedWeekend.getDate()+1 | date :  "dd" }}
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            {{ selectedWeekend.getDate()+2 | date :  "dd" }}
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            {{ selectedWeekend.getDate()+3 | date :  "dd" }}
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            {{ selectedWeekend.getDate()+4 | date :  "dd" }}
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            {{ selectedWeekend.getDate()+5 | date :  "dd" }}
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            {{ selectedWeekend.getDate()+6 | date :  "dd" }}
        </td>

        <td style="padding: 10px;">
            {{ selectedWeekend.getDate()+7 | date :  "dd" }}
        </td>

    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do give some example?

Comment: Found another work around in my another question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387646/angular-4-typescript-construct-array-of-dates-of-subsequent-7-days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387646/angular-4-typescript-construct-array-of-dates-of-subsequent-7-days)

Comment: have you founded the solution tho this

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to initialize selectedWeekend

```
 public selectedWeekend: Date = new Date();
```

If you set the value somewhere else, ensure is Date type

Comment: It is fetched from database

Comment: And how do you set up the selectedWeekend value from the database?, What I mean is , at some point in time you are doing  this.selectedWeekend = 'something here'. Please share that code.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand correctly what you are looking for, you want to take all weekdays from a selected date. 
The best option to use Date options is using moment.js (https://momentjs.com/)

In this case, you can use weekday method, what returns a Date object with the day you are looking for. After that, using get method you can get the number of day.

```
moment(selectedWeekend).weekday(7).get('D')
```

Where 7 is how many days you want to get after the selectedWeekend

Hope it helps you

Comment: I want the solution in Angular 4 and typescript

Comment: Yes sure, it works on angular 4. You have to import moment in your .ts file. After that, you have to define a method when you select a date, and use moment

Comment: First of all, install it -> **npm install moment --save**. Then, import it -> ``import * as moment from 'moment';``

Comment: Cant we do it using simpl getDate or setDate in Component.ts?