# Angular 4 Typescript - Construct Array of Dates of subsequent 7 Days

Tags: angular, typescript

I want construct an array of 7 dates. those dates will be 7 subsequent days from a SelectedDate. I have written following code in Component.ts

```
public selectedWeekDates: Date [];

public selectedWeek: Date = new Date();

SetSelectedWeekDates(): void {
    var dte = new Date();
    dte = this.selectedWeek;
    for (let i: number = 1; i < 8; i++) {            
        this.selectedWeekDates[i - 1].setDate(dte.getDate() + i);
    }

}
```

my html is as follows

```
.
.
.
<ng-container *ngFor="let dates of selectedWeekDates">
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
        {{ dates| date:"dd" }}
    </div>
</ng-container>
.
.
.
```

I am getting below error in console

> TypeError: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
>     at xxxComponent.prototype.SetSelectedWeekDates (eval code:179:143)

May I know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: I tried declaring it as public selectedWeekDates: Array<Date> = [];

Comment: try to check it ```for (let i: number = 1; i < 8; i++) {  
        if(this.selectedWeekDates[i - 1]){
          this.selectedWeekDates[i - 1].setDate(dte.getDate() + i);
        }         
    }```

Comment: I guess you are accessing null element in your array `this.selectedWeekDates[i - 1].setDate(dte.getDate() + i);`, you should try `this.selectedWeekDates.push()`

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal No luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function, you are using `setDate` function on elements of `this.selectedWeekDates` while they are undefined. You should use `this.selectedWeek` or `dte` to get and set your dates as below:

```
SetSelectedWeekDates(): void {
    let dte: Date = new Date(this.selectedWeek);        
     for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {            
        this.selectedWeekDates[i-1]=new Date(dte.setDate(dte.getDate() + 1));
        }

}
```

Also instead of adding `i` after getDate(), add 1 as done above as setDate() function is incrementing `dte` by a day in every iteration which means dte is updated after every iteration.

Comment: I displayed dte in Console Log. While using new Date() the log is Tue Nov 20 2018 14:21:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
 when this.selectedWeek is assigned dynamically from a database value then it is 2018-09-30T00:00:00. Does this have to do something with this issue?

Comment: It is because it is showing the default format returned by `new Date()`. You can convert it to any other format you want. As`setDate()` function updates the date it is called with but returns number in miliseconds so i converted it using new Date() in the loop for storing dates in `this.selectedWeekDates`

Comment: If `dte` is showing today's date than it means that `this.selectedWeek` has todays date instead of 2018-09-30T00:00:00 because of this line ` dte = this.selectedWeek;`.

Comment: @captainsac Good. Edited as you suggested.

Comment: Accepting this answer after multiple trial and edits

Answer (score 0):

Your `selectedWeekDates` is empty. Hence the error. Give this a try to fix it:

```
public selectedWeekDates: Date[] = new Array(7).fill(new Date());

public selectedWeek: Date = new Date();

SetSelectedWeekDates(): void {
    var dte = new Date();
    dte = this.selectedWeek;
    for (let i: number = 1; i < 8; i++) {            
        this.selectedWeekDates[i - 1].setDate(dte.getDate() + i);
    }

}
```

This should fix the current error that you're getting. I'm not really sure what it is that you're trying to achieve here. So you might need to fix your logic a bit. All I'm able to see on the screen is 27, 7 times.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dates-array-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Sorry but it is giving error ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getDate'

Comment: Really? Not sure why, but I'm not able to see any such errors on the console. I just used the exact same logic as yours in the `SetSelectedWeekDates` method.

Comment: I displayed dte in Console Log. While using new Date() the log is Tue Nov 20 2018 14:21:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) when this.selectedWeek is assigned dynamically from a database value then it is 2018-09-30T00:00:00. Does this have to do something with this issue?